# Get Type of Lambda using Roslyn and VB

Tags: vb.net, lambda, roslyn

How do I get the Type of a Lambda using Visual Basic?

```
SyntaxKind.FunctionLambdaHeader,
SyntaxKind.MultiLineFunctionLambdaExpression,
SyntaxKind.MultiLineSubLambdaExpression,
SyntaxKind.SingleLineFunctionLambdaExpression,
SyntaxKind.SingleLineSubLambdaExpression,
SyntaxKind.SubLambdaHeader
```

I am not sure I need to deal with all 6 above

I want to be able to add an As Clause to variable declarations like below.

```
Dim startPointGetter = Function(part As EnvDTE.vsCMPart) arg.GetStartPoint(part)
```

I don't even know how I would specify the As Clause manually so I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out the type, at least, you can use `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo` to figure out the underlying type.

Comment: If you mean `Dim lTypeInfo As TypeInfo = model.GetTypeInfo(ExpressionValue)', where ExpressionValue is one of the ones listed above, then I get `lTypeInfo.convertedType.ToString = Function <generated method>(part As EnvDTE.vsCMPart) As EnvDTE.TextPoint` but that still doesn't let me create a simple AsClause that makes any sense.

Comment: Starting with `Dim endPointGetter = Function(part As EnvDTE.vsCMPart) arg.GetEndPoint(part)` I get `Dim endPointGetter As Function <generated method>(part As EnvDTE.vsCMPart) As EnvDTE.TextPoint= Function(part As EnvDTE.vsCMPart) arg.GetEndPoint(part)`